# Android - AsyncTask Returning String Array

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I asked a question earlier referring to an error I had pertaining to displaying JSON data in a ListView. I was pointed to AsyncTask, which confuses me very much. I want the JSON data to be parsed and set to a String[] array in my AsyncTask. I read the documentation, by the way. I need help on how to do that. This was my faulty code:

```
class ShowTitlesTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Integer, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {
            URL jsonURL = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/illbehonest/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");
            URLConnection jc = jsonURL.openConnection();
            InputStream is = jc.getInputStream();
            String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);

            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);

            JSONObject jdata = json.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray jentry = jdata.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int entryNumber = 0; entryNumber<=25; entryNumber++){
                    JSONObject entry = jentry.getJSONObject(entryNumber);
                    String[][] jtitle = {entry.getString("title")};
                    params = jtitle;
            }
            return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();                
            URL jsonURL = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/illbehonest/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");
            URLConnection jc = jsonURL.openConnection();
            InputStream is = jc.getInputStream();
            String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);

            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);

            JSONObject jdata = json.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray jentry = jdata.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int entryNumber = 0; entryNumber<=jentry.lenght(); entryNumber++){
                    JSONObject entry = jentry.getJSONObject(entryNumber);
                    result.add(entry.getString("title");
            }

            return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
    }
```

By the way, some of the methods used by you in `doInBackground` throw different exceptions, so you'll have to surround them by an `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your only problem but in your method header you show that the method returns

`String[]`

but you actually return `null`